# how to set an image instead of a title custom dialog android

Tags: android

Hello i'm implementing a custom dialog. I have a class which extends `Dialog`. The problem is that i don't want to have a title, instead i want to show an image in the title bar. Can this be accomplished?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class that extends Dialog, then make a call to requestWindowFeature with no title.

```
public class CustomizeDialog extends Dialog
{
    public CustomizeDialog(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        /** It will hide the title */
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.popup);
```

Then you can create your pop up xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="10dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/YOUR_ID" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Close"
        android:src="@drawable/YOUR_DRAWABLE"
            android:background="@null" />
```

Then you can inflate your pop up from java

```
CustomizeDialog customizeDialog = new CustomizeDialog(YOUR_CONTEXT);
customizeDialog.show();
```

Comment: what is `this.instamapMedia = instamapMedia;` doing?

Comment: it is my custom code, sorry for that, I deleted that row above